# Pivot selected columns into rows with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a column-based table like this:

[image: Column-Based Table]

And I need to convert it to a row-based table like this:

[image: Row-Based Table]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the sample data and expected output as text not as image. Also what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need an UNPIVOT -

```
SELECT OrgID, Property, DataValue
FROM (SELECT OrgID, Property, DataValue
      FROM YOUR_TABLE
      UNPIVOT
      (
            DataValue FOR Property IN (ExtensionDigits
                                      ,StartExtension
                                      ,LastUsedExtension
                                      ,Server1IP
                                      ,Server2IP
                                      ,ServerPort
                                      ,IsFunctionOn
                                      ,VolumeDecibel)
      ) unpvt) temp
WHERE DataValue IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! thank you for understanding the simple thing I tried to accomplish. I did run into issues with INT and BIT conversions in the UNPIVOT but I was able to work through them by casting the results into VARCHAR in the SELECT statement. I'm new to this but learning quickly. Thanks again!